# Json response displayed

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

I'm new to both symfony and ajax , i want to submit a form without refreshing the page everytime i was following along with [this](http://intelligentbee.com/blog/2015/01/19/symfony-2-forms-and-ajax/) tutorial , everything working the page does submit to the database but the problem is that i get this message in the browser

```
{"message":"Success!"}
```

This is what i have in my controller .

```
$bon = new Bons();
    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\BonsType', $bon);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($bon);
        $em->flush();

        return new JsonResponse(array('message' => 'Success!'), 200);
    }

    return $this->render('bons/new.html.twig', array(
        'bon' => $bon,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
```

The ajax part :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('body').on('submit', '.myForm', function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: $(this).attr('method'),
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                data: $(this).serialize()
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                if (typeof data.message !== 'undefined') {
                    alert(data.message);
                }
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if (typeof jqXHR.responseJSON !== 'undefined') {
                    if (jqXHR.responseJSON.hasOwnProperty('form')) {
                        $('#form_body').html(jqXHR.responseJSON.form);
                    }

                    $('.form_error').html(jqXHR.responseJSON.message);

                } else {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }

            });
        });
    });
```

is there any way to submit the form without redirecting or refreshing the page

Comment: First you said you did this code because you didn't want to refresh the page every time and at the bottom you ask if there is a way to refresh the page... which is it?

Comment: Oh , i didn't notice that , i actually meant the first , submitting without refreshing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out your problem was really simple. You just need to add the dataType like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: $(this).attr('method'),
    dataType: "json",
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    data: $(this).serialize()
})
```

**I want to show you what I normally do**

My php file looks like this:

```
$json = array();
$my_variable = $_POST('variable_name'); // or however I get the value
if(something == something)
    $json['success'] = 'It was successful';
else
    $json['error'] = 'Something went wrong';
die(json_encode($json));
```

My JS looks like this:

```
$('.update_class').click(function(){
    var variable_I_am_sending = $(this).data('something');
    $.post('path_to_php', {variable_name: variable_I_am_sending}, function(data, result, xhr){
        if(result == 'success')
            if(data.success)
                alert(data.success);
            else
                alert(data.error);
        else
            alert('ajax call failed');
    }, "json");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Chris , what i'm getting is {"message":"Success!"} in the browser , instead i want to get that message in an alert box

Comment: If data.message is giving you {"message": "Success!"} It means that the object actually looks like this: {"message": {"message": "Success!"}}. So what you could try is this: data.message.message
Can you please do me a favor and add this before your alert and tell me what it outputs in the console: console.log(data);

Comment: This is what i get after clicking the submit button . [link](http://prnt.sc/ajnm5k)  , i also tried  data.message.message but got the same result .

Comment: Oh your problem is actually really simple... just add dataType: "json"

Comment: I added it to the answer, you can check it out and try it, I am sure it will solve your problem.

Comment: Are you sure you included Jquery?

Comment: i think i'm the dumbest programmer ever Chris , there was a typo in my including of JQuery  instead of src="jquery.js" i typed src="jqurey.js" . thank you so much for your time Chris , Much appreciated .